# Unique Key Pair Generation on Android

Tags: android, security, random

I have been trying to generate unique key pairs in android. Can anyone tell me why the following always produces the same key the first time it is called?

```
long ltime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SecureRandom random = null;
    random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] seed = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(ltime).array();
    random.nextBytes(seed);
    RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
    try {
        mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(spec, random);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mKeyPair = mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    mPublicKey = (PublicKey) mKeyPair.getPublic();
    mPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) mKeyPair.getPrivate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Always generate the same key, because [SecureRandom](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html) with a seed is deterministic and always produce a same result. Just don't set the seed, this can be insecure as you can read on bibliography:

**Seeding SecureRandom may be insecure**

> A seed is an array of bytes used to bootstrap random number
>   generation. To produce cryptographically secure random numbers, both
>   the seed and the algorithm must be secure.
>
> By default, instances of this class will generate an initial seed
>   using an internal entropy source, such as /dev/urandom. This seed is
>   unpredictable and appropriate for secure use.

Just use a KeyPairGenerator class:

```
    KeyPair keys = null;
    try {
        RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(spec);
        keys = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(keys != null){
        PublicKey mPublicKey = (PublicKey) keys.getPublic();
        PrivateKey mPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keys.getPrivate();
    }
```

Comment: No it is still the same key every time. Man this is driving me nuts.

Comment: It seems pretty straight forward, but I have a unit test that creates and instance of this and the key is always the same.

Comment: Do you try generate RSA keys with KeyPairGenerator?

Comment: Yes that is what I am using. I may be incorrectly assuming that it is generating the same keys. I need to do some more testing with my objects thanks for confirming I am doing it right.

Comment: I test this code and the keys are not the same, maybe have many equals bytes, but are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer to this question was to add spongy castle from bouncy castle to my application.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution for this was to add the spongycastle provider to my application. Once I did that the keys started being random.